# how to exit a while loop through a function in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, function-pointers

Let's assume **mf_ptr** is a typedef of member function pointer of a class. And we have the flowing code:

```
map<string, mb_ptr> cmd_table;
cmd_table["exit"] = &class_name::exit;
string cmd;
while (cin >> cmd){
    (this->*cmd_table[cmd])();
}
```

So how should i define the function exit() to exit the while loop?

Comment: You really want to pick some other name for the function -- `exit` is part of the standard library.

Comment: this isn't an answer to ure question so I'll make it a comment: I'd personally go with:

    while(cin >> cmd && cmd != "exit") {
        (this->*cmd_table[cmd])();
    }

Comment: @JerryCoffin exit is a member function here, I don't think we need another name.

Comment: @NadirMuzaffar maybe you've gave the best answer thought it's not the answer to my question. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Raise an exception in the exit function, and catch it in the while loop.
2. Have all your functions return a boolean, whether or not to exit the while loop.

Comment: Another option is to pass in a pointer to a boolean, and let the function set it if exit.

Comment: That's too bad, but sometimes that's the answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: On a different note - just create a `bool cmd_dispatcher(istream& cmd_in)` and call `while (cmd_dispatcher(cin));` ...

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
while (cin >> cmd && !class_name::exitLoop){
    (this->*cmd_table[cmd])();
}
```

Where `class_name::exitLoop` would be set to true by `class_name::exit()`.

I'd personally go with:

```
while(cin >> cmd && cmd != "exit") {
    (this->*cmd_table[cmd])();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use (the way you specified it as above):

```
class_name::exit(void) { cin.setstate(eofbit); ... }
...
while(cin >> cmd)
    (this->*cmd_table[cmd])();
```

in which case the loop will terminate *after* processing the `exit` command (next iteration round the `>>` will fail).

If you want to go for a larger amount of complexity, you could create a custom *stream extraction operator*,

```
friend istream & operator>>(istream & is, class_name::CmdExecutorClass &comm)
{
    string cmd;
    cin >> cmd;
    if (cmd == "exit")
        cin.setstate(eofbit);
    else
        (comm.table[cmd])();
    return is;
}
```

The advantage of that I can see is that you could simply write:

```
while (cin >> cmd);
```

and you could handle errors / unknown commands (e.g. `std::map<...>::operator[]` *adds to the map* if no element exists for the key - that may not be what you want).
But you also need quite some glue to create the `CmdExecutor` class (constructor or templating to pass the `table[]` reference in from the embedding "master" class, ...). For a simple case, overkill.

**Edit:** Should also add that *closing* `cin` (that's what setting the `eof` bit does, effectively) may be unwanted as well. The `fail` bit (which could be cleared again afterwards) is probably a better option.

Comment: I vote up because your answer is helpful.But..Your first approach may gain the best efficiency here，but the exit() only work when the condition of while loop is cin>>cmd, and that's not obvious. In your second approach, the ">>" operator does the work we don't expect the >> will do, that's dangerous. And while (cin >> cmd); is confusing.

Comment: @Mike: I actually agree with all the points you made. Personally, I think stream insertion/extraction operators are one of the cancers of C++ ("[ ... ] `>>` does the work we don't expect `>>` to do ..."). I admit I merely saw this as one of the challenges "how compact can you make it" ;-)